# Change Report Name On PDF when exporting from report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a working report, but I'd like to change the report name. By default it uses the RDL filename. I'd like to set different name for the downloaded files.

Is there a way to generate the file name for reports downloaded from SSRS dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

Please try using DisplayName Property of ReportViewer

```
ReportViewer.ServerReport.DisplayName = <Your Parameter Value>;
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = <Your Parameter Value>;
```

Comment: Great, Please mark if it's useful.. that will help others facing similar problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a data driven subscription you can set the report name dynamically with SQL.

Otherwise there is no way to do this within SSRS. You could always use an external script to rename the PDF for you after export but it isn't completely automatic.

Comment: NO I am not using data driven subscription

Comment: Then I feel you're out of luck.

Comment: any  way to change the Click event

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using a Javascript hook. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.reportsyouneed.com/blog/ssrs-adding-date-to-exported-filenames) which got me started but didn't fully work for me.

What I ended up doing was adding some javascript to ReportViewer.aspx in `<sql server folder>\ReportServer\Pages\`, in a script tag at the end of the `<body>`. The checks against the URL ensure that it only affects reports it is supposed to change the name on.

This works fine with spaces and other special characters (as long as they're allowed in a file name).

```
function modifyExportFileName() {
    /* Change the name of file exports */ 
    var filename = false;

    if (window.location.href.indexOf('Folder/Report') !== -1) { //it's the report we want
        filename = getParameter('parameter'); // returns false if not set
        // should also have access to report DOM here, also Date(), etc.
    } // could add more here as needed in else if blocks


    if (filename) { // we have a filename set.
        console.log('changing filename of exported reports to ' + filename);
        changeFilename(filename);
    }
}

function getParameter(param) {
    //case sensitive parameter extractor.
    var l = window.location.href;
    if (l.indexOf(param + '=' > -1)) {
        var param_location = l.indexOf(param + '=') + (param + '=').length;
        return l.substring(param_location, l.indexOf('&', param_location + 1));
    }
    return false;
}

function changeFilename(filename) {
    var r = null,
        url = null;

    try {
        r = this.$find('ReportViewerControl')._getInternalViewer();
    } catch(e) {
        setTimeout(function () {changeFilename(filename)}, 1000); //maybe we're not done loading.
        console.log("trying again");
        return false;
    }

    url = r.ExportUrlBase;
    if (url) {
        var i = url.indexOf('FileName='),
            j = url.indexOf('&', i+1);
        r.ExportUrlBase = url.substring(0, i) + 'FileName=' + filename + url.substring(j);
        console.log('reset filename to ' + filename);
    }
}

modifyExportFileName();
```

Edit: I noticed that this code didn't run in IE on the corporate network. The reason is the console.logs. Comment them out if your site is running in IE Compatibility mode, as IE5 didn't have a console.